# How to prevent against booby-traps

Tags: clash-of-clans

When attacking a base my troops have been decimated with booby traps (springs, bombs). Is there any way to counter this? I would space my troops out but this lessens the troops affected by spells such as rage and healing.

Comment: You could throw down a few barbarians down at the spots you expect traps to pop up. Other than that there is no reliable way to deal with them.

Comment: @Izzo this is very hard to do if you had already deployed giants to destroy the walls. Maybe it's a thought that you could deploy giants and barbarians at the same time and since barbarians move faster the traps would be "wasted" on them.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to anticipate where you think traps are.  For instance, if you notice there are holes inside the base where there are no defenses, chances are a trap is there.  You can guess at what kind of trap by the size and shape of the hole - big bombs and teslas both require a 2x2 area to deploy in.

If you don't see any holes in the base at all, chances are the traps are around the outside.

Once you kind of have an idea as to where the traps are, it's time to bait them as best you can.  It's hard to bait traps deep inside a base, but relatively easy around the outside.

For traps around the outside of a base, dropping cheap troops or dropping a small first wave usually helps.  For instance, if they're outside the base, drop a couple of barbarians strategically around and see if you can trip them.  If barbarians won't immediately walk to where the traps are (ie, they are protecting other defenses and there are trash buildings in the way) drop one giant in the area you plan to attack and let him walk up to the base.

Once you've baited the traps, you can drop the bulk of your army, which will group them together enough for spells to be effective.  You're basically sacrificing the initial troop(s) to protect the rest of your troops from getting hit.  It's much better to have one giant hit a spring trap than 10, for instance.

If the traps are really deep inside the base, there may not be anything you can do - you can try to reserve a few troops for a last-minute push, and let the others attack and potentially get hit by the traps.  However, if you're evenly matched and the enemy has a smart base design, chances are the traps are going to be effective no matter what precautions you take.

As a side note, if you see that the person hasn't logged in in a long time (ie, all builders are idle, no league shield, lots of tombstones, etc), chances are their traps aren't even armed anymore.  Someone else has probably already jumped on that (literal) grenade for you.  Therefore, you can attack with a bit more confidence.

Also, note that you should learn from your raiding failures - the things you see that are particularly effective in other people's bases can help you design your own impenetrable trap maze.

Comment: Nicely put. And also triggering traps depends on what sort of troops you have. Say you have trained hogs, then you need to watch out for those giant bombs, rest are not that harmful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to focus on these key points to disarm Traps effectively:

> 1. Know where to anticipate Traps (this can depend what on what kind of troops you’re using)
> 2. Know how to disarm the traps

I think the best way to address these points is to just start and you will get it pretty fast.

Find more details about this strategy here:

[Prevent your attacks getting blasted by Traps Part 1](http://www.allclash.com/prevent-attacks-getting-blasted-traps-2/)

[Prevent your attacks getting blasted by Traps Part 2](http://www.allclash.com/prevent-attacks-getting-blasted-traps-3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's better to summarise the information from links in your answer than just post the links. That way, if the links change or break, your answer will still be useful.